# vim macro to break up long Java method declaration

Tags: vim

I have a long method declaration like this

```
public void doSomething(C1 v1, C2 v2, C3 v3, C4 v4, C5 v5, C6 v6, C7 v7) {
```

I want to break this up to look like this

```
public void doSomething(
        C1 v1,
        C2 v2,
        C3 v3,
        C4 v4,
        C5 v5,
        C6 v6,
        C7 v7)
{
```

Is there a vim macro I can make to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two steps:

```
V:s/[(,)]/&\r/g
V'<=
```

Comment: What does the capital V mean?

Comment: @three_cups_of_java: `V` is to enter visual mode in a line-wise manner. You map that to a shortcut so it's easier to type, and does it all at once: `nnoremap <silent> ,bm V:s/[(,)]/&\r/g<CR>V'<='>` — all you have to do is to put the cursor anywhere on the method line and press `,bm` (or whatever you used) in normal mode.

Comment: This is great! Where can I find out more about the V'<= step? (Google has trouble searching for things like <=)

Comment: Found my answers here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html. Thanks again!

Comment: No need for google, try `:h V`, `:h motion`, `:h '<`, and `:h =`. BTW, I wonder ... yes! `='<` is enough. No need to fall back into visual mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Luc Hermitte's solution, but another solution would be :

`0f,a<CR>` the first time (go to the start, then go the first comma)

`;.` then, to repeat the two actions.

Sometime it's faster ;)